What does it mean for two random variables to be identically distributed?
Let $(\Omega_1, \Sigma_1, \mathbb{P}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \Sigma_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$ be two probability spaces. Suppose we have a random variables $X_1: \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X_2: \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$. We say that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed if $$\mu_1(A) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \in A) = \mathbb{P}(X_2 \in A) = \mu_2(A),$$ for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Borel.
Now, I understand what the definition is saying but I want to gain some intuition on what it is trying to convey. For example, say $X_1$ and $X_2$ are simple random variables (theit range if finite), we can say that $$\mathbb{P}(X_1 = z) = \mathbb{P}(X_2 = z),$$ for every $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this imply that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same range?

You might think about the possibility that $X_2$ takes more values than $X_1$, but only on sets of measure 0.

@JamieRadcliffe: Great point. Is this the only way they can "differ"?

$\def\essrange{\mathop{\mathrm{essrange}}}$One way you might phrase it is that ``essential range'' of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the same, where $\essrange(X) = {z ;:;\mathbb{P}(X=z)>0}$. Since the essential range is determined by the probabilities with which $X_1$ and $X_2$ take certain values and these probabilities agree since $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution, we have $$ \essrange(X_1) = \essrange(X_2) . $$
